# Installing Huawei ec156 modem on ubuntu 10.10

Tags: modem, ubuntu-10.10

I have Tata Photon Data Card. It is using Huawei EC156 modem. I am using ubuntu 10.10.
It is not getting detected. I tried with network connections also. But no success. Is there any way out?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/78164/configuring-tata-photon-usb-modem-huawei-ec156

Comment: This post talks about ubuntu 11.10. usb-modeswitch-1.2.0 and usb-modeswitch-data is already installed.